# What's the appropriate type for a lazyloaded property?

Tags: linq, subsonic

If I have a Customer class and want to add a Orders property which would return all orders for this customer, what would be the appropriate type for the Orders property?

Some of the possible choices I can think of:

- List
- IList
- IEnumerable

Answer (score 3):

Generally the least possible type is preferable. If you can get away with IEnumerable - do it. Then IList<> etc. The more basic the list type, the easier it will be to work with the class later in the app's life.

Comment: The Orders property will be populated by calling repository.Find<Order>(x => x.CustomerId == this.CustomerId) which returns an IList. Therefore, doesn't it makes sense to use IList as the type for the Orders property?

Answer (score 1):

ReadOnlyCollection<Order> or IEnumerable<Order> are both good choices. If you return IEnumerable<T>, make sure the user cannot cast the returned object into another type and modify it (or, if they do, they will not modify the state of the Customer class).

Comment: How would I make sure the use cannot cast into another type?